# What are the best places to go for a hike near Mexico City?

Tags: hiking

What are the best places in Mexico City to go for a hike. Ideally they should be safe, with amazing views, can go with my car with two or three other people, they are not so crowded, last for approximately 3-5 hours and are not technically difficult.

Comment: What do you mean by go on a ride? Do you mean their is some sort of public transportation to get to the location, or do you mean the trails are bike-able?

Comment: Welcome awavi! What level of hiking are you looking for, in terms of difficulty? How much experience do you and the people you'll be traveling with have? Also, how much time do you plan on spending?

Comment: Not too professional. Only to enjoy the day walk for 3-5 hours. Not putting my life in danger. By ride never mind. I miss said it. I meant to be accesible by car.

Comment: Unfortunately Mexico City and rural is not that *safe*.